# Which locale does a stream have by default

Tags: c++, localization

All C++ input and output streams have an associated locale; the [`std::ios_base::getloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/getloc) method returns a [`std::locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) by value, so that value must have been set up during construction. The locale can be changed after construction of the stream, using the [`imbue()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/imbue) mutator. But what is the default locale for a stream? What locale does a stream of the standard library classes (`std::ofstream`, etc) have just after construction? And what is the locale of the standard streams (`std::cout`, `std:cerr` and `std:log`) on program start?

The documentation I've seen for the stream constructors is unhelpful.

Comment: I am answering my own question, as is encouraged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ultimate base class of all streams, [`std::basic_ios`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios), requires that the constructors of all streams call the initialization method [`std::basic_ios::init`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init). That method initializes the locale of the stream to be the locale given by the [`std::locale` default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale). That default constructor constructs a copy of the "global locale", which is the ["classic" locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/classic) by default, if the global locale has not been changed (using [`std::locale::global()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/global)).

Hence, the default locale for all streams will usually be the "classic" locale.